# Is there a way I can get the shower arm to tighten in the 12 o'clock position?

Tags: shower

I bought an extender arm for my shower head, but when it screws tight the arm doesn't end up in the 12 o'clock position. I've had some progress of tightened position with teflon tape, but it's not predicatable and loosens easy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Teflon tape effectively you can turn your arm through a range of angles without substantially affecting tightness. Start over and make sure you're using enough. You shouldn't actually bottom out the threaded fitting.

Comment: And since a shower head typically doesn't need to support a lot of pressure (unless it's one with a shutoff valve directly on the shower head itself), the Teflon tape idea is probably the best solution.